# VNC display of macOS Catalina frozen on login screen after reconnect

Tags: mac-mini, catalina, performance, remote-desktop

I have revived my Mac Mini 3,1 with Catalina thanks to dosdude1's patcher - and so far, it worked great! But, this is actually a Mac Mini Server (from 2009). So the obvious application is to deploy it as a server - a home server, to be exact.

So I enabled remote administration (to also allow SSH) in order to also enable screen sharing. Then I made sure that VNC access is secured through a password. And when I connected the first time, it seemed perfectly fine. But eversince then, even after rebooting my PC, when I connect to the Mac Mini, I see two mouse cursors and neither of them moves. It's essentially frozen.

I read about a bug in Mojave where you'd get an infinite login screen with certain settings - but this is Catalina, it should be fixed...I think?